# Bulk software installation

Tags: windows-7, installation

I'm doing a software installation on a lot of computers, I'm installing windows 7 pro and then installing each program individually (with a script and silent installs). Is there a better way of doing this?

I've looked at the windows image method but it requires a volume licence which I do not have.

The computers all have wiped hard drives hence the fresh install.

Comment: take images individually for each computer. this way you won't need a volume licence.

Comment: Please link to the information that makes you think creating images require a volume license.

Comment: @Ramhound https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee523217(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: There is not a single statement on that website that says you must have a volume license to create your own installation media.

Comment: Ninite is a great tool for installing multiple applications at once. It can't be used for custom applications, but they have an extensive list of popular ones.